# TinyMCE and a jQuery Mobile textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, tinymce

This would seem to be super simple but I cannot get it to work nor can I find the answer.

I have a textarea (editcontent) and in my onLoad function I tried this:

```
$('#editcontent').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url: 'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

    // General options
    theme: "advanced", 
    plugins:"pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
```

When I get to this page, the textarea is there in the DOM but does not show up on the screen (I am checking this on Chrome). I know the script locations are correct. What am I missing?

Comment: set up an example of what you have on JSFiddle, you can include all the javascript and css files you need to set up the example using the "resources" box on the left hand side. It will help someone to help you. Or at very least give a url to see if your live version on your site

Comment: I have edited the question to fix the code formatting but it looks like you are missing the closing brackets. Is this a paste error or an error in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lee, the problem that I think I have with JSFiddle is that it does not include JQ mobile so it cannot adequately reflect the behavior I am having.

Comment: ya, sry, it was just a cut and paste... sry I didnt explain that... I have figured out an alternative that I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I only have one textarea, I just used the tinymce init way of doing it.  I am sure it could be done the other way but I dont know what was wrong.

SO:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"        
    });
```

This works for me on my one textarea... I just didnt want to have to declare ALL textareas as tinyMCE boxes (even though I am technically only using one).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it, to have TinyMCE work, you need to apply 3 things correctly:

1) Place tiny_mce.js script file in the correct folder

2) Fetch TinyMCE script file in the  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

3) Initiate TinyMCE document ready with the options you like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,bullist,numlist",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this init function setting to make it work for one or more editor instances

```
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode: 'exact',
    elements : "id_of_texarea, id_of_textarea2, id_of_a_div",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : ... 
  });
```